# Writing an unmanaged DLL to be used in a .NET project: best practices

Tags: integration, unmanaged

I'm planning on implementing a performance-critical part of an otherwise completely managed project in C (or C++). What are the best practices (concerning method signatures, calling conventions, whatever else there is between two worlds) to follow?

So far I have:

- Function declaration (or definition?) should be `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`
- Calling convention is `__stdcall`

Anything else? I'm sure there's a lot.

Comment: Sure, don't do it.  Write the code in C++/CLI, C++ Interop is much faster than pinvoke.  And of course: measure first.  Only way you'll know if you *need* to look for a faster implementation.